# comparison contour results from Canny algorithm and similarity

Tags: algorithm, comparison, computer-vision, similarity, contour

How can i compare contours retrieve from Canny algorithm and get a similarity response? 
There is any comparison algorithm based on contours or i have to do one from scratch?
There is any "platform" like opencv or similar (better in python or java)?

Answer (score 1):

One of the most effective contour matching methods is called [Shape Context](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_context).  It is not implemented in OpenCV, but a C++ implementation is available [here](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~zhengyf/PointMatching.htm).